# How to show Result after selecting dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-5, cascadingdropdown

I want to show Course Code after selecting a department from drop down. 
it searches from database and get but does not show at browser. Here is the drop down:

```html
 <select name="Id" id="Id">
                        <option value="">Select Department</option>
                        @foreach (var departments in ViewBag.ShowDepartments)
                        {
                            <option value="@departments.Id">@departments.Name</option>
                        }
                    </select>
```

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Id").change(function() {
            var departmentId = $("#Id").val();

            var json = { departmentId: departmentId };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ViewAllScheduleByDept", "ClassSchedule")',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(json),
                success: function (data) {

                    //$("#myTable").append('<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>');

                    $('#Code').val(data.Code);
                    //$('#ContactNo').val(data.ContactNo);
                    //$('#Type').val(data.Type);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

I am using mvc.

Comment: how does your ViewAllScheduleByDept method looks like ? what are you returning from that ?

Comment: Hi there. Please do not add "ASAP" to your questions, or beg for urgency in other ways. The **volunteers** here may get around to your question, and if they do so it will be at their leisure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work fine as long as `ViewAllScheduleByDept` action method returns a json structure with a `Code` property.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewAllScheduleByDept(int departmentId)
{  
   //values hardcoded for demo. you may replace it value from db table(s)
   return Json( new { Code="HardcodedValue", ContactNo="12345"} );
}
```

and you have an input form element with Id property value as Code in your page

```
<input type="text" id="Code" />
```

and you do not have any other script errors which is preventing your js code to execute.

Also, since you are sending just the Id value, you don't really need to use `JSON.stringify` method and no need to specify `contentType` property value.

```
$("#Id").change(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ViewAllScheduleByDept", "ClassSchedule")',
        data: { departmentId: $("#Id").val() },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.Code);
            $('#Code').val(data.Code);
        }
        ,error:function(a, b, c) {
            alert("Error" + c);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: My Method is:-                                                                                       public JsonResult ViewAllScheduleByDept(int departmentId)
        {
            var schedules = GetAllSchedule();
            var scheduleList = schedules.Where(a => a.departmentId == departmentId).ToList();
            return Json(scheduleList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: So  what is happening ? You are making a POST ajax request to the method.

Answer (score 0):

use last before append

```
$("#myTable").last().append("<tr><td>ID</td></tr><tr><td>Name</td></tr>");
```

please see the link for details

[Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)